# Rearrange array

Tags: php, arrays

Array starts like this:

```
Array ( 
  [SMART Board] => Array ( [0] => sb1 [1] => sb2 [2] => sb3 ) 
  [Projector] => Array ( [0] => pr1 [1] => pr2 [2] => pr3 ) 
  [Speakers] => Array ( [0] => sp1 [1] => sp2 [2] => sp3 ) 
  [Splitter] => Array ( [0] => spl1 [1] => spl2 [2] => spl3 ) 
  [Wireless Slate] => Array ( [0] => ws1 [1] => ws2 [2] => ws3 ) 
)
```

The keys are used as my table columns titles. Their individual arrays are to carry the column information.

I have split it up even further with `array_slice` and `array_merge_recursive` to look pretty as 2 arrays - 1 holds the column names, the other looks like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => sb1  
  [1] => sb2  
  [2] => sb3  
  [3] => pr1  
  [4] => pr2  
  [5] => pr3  
  [6] => sp1  
  [7] => sp2  
  [8] => sp3  
  [9] => spl1  
  [10] => spl2  
  [11] => spl3  
  [12] => ws1  
  [13] => ws2  
  [14] => ws3  
)
```

However, when trying to write the table I'm getting keys 0, 1, 2 as the column data, then row break then 3, 4, 5 then row break... etc.

I need it to be 0, 3, 6, 9, 12 row break 1, 4, 7, 10, 13 row break etc...

How can I either rearrange my array to allow for this, or rewrite how the data goes into the table so that the correct information lines up with the appropriate column?

```
foreach(unserialize($dl->data) as $data){

    //first 3 are specialinstructions, system, and room
    $uniques = array_slice($data,0,3);

    $rows = array_slice($data,3);
    $rows2 = array_merge_recursive($rows2, $rows);

    //get the specialinstructions, system, and room
    foreach($uniques as $unique){
        echo $unique."<br/>";
    }///foreach uniques

    echo "<br>";

}///foreach unserialized

$numberofrooms = count($rows2[key($rows2)]);
$numberofproducts = count($rows2);
print_r($rows2);

unset($rows);

//write the individual rows
foreach($rows2 as $header=>$rowset){

    $headers[] = $header;

    foreach($rowset as $row){

        $rows[] = $row;

    }//foreach rowset

}//foreach rows2

echo "<p>";
print_r($rows);

echo '<table class="data-table">
          <caption>DL</caption>

          <thead><tr>';
foreach($headers as $header){
    echo "<th>".$header."</th>";
}
echo '</tr></thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
$i = 0;
foreach($rows as $row){
    if($i == 3 || $i == 0){
        echo "<tr>";
        $i = 1;
    }
    echo '<td>'.$row.'</td>';
    if($i == 2){
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    $i++;
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: As a hint: Imo it is much easier to grasp the structure of the code if you don't `echo` the HTML. Do it this way, e.g.: `<?php foreach($headers as $header):?> <th><?php echo $header ?></th> <?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: Thanks Felix, I normally go with that. However this is wrapped up in a function and I feel it's cleaner to see exactly what I'm outputting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the original array and the following code to display the way you want:

```
$i=0;
while($i<3){ // 3 is the number of items in each array
    foreach($originalArray as $arr){
        print($arr[$i].'<br/>');
    }
    print('<hr/>');
    $i++;
}
```

Not tested but you should get the drift.

Comment: Perfect! A little modification to fit my script and bingo, we have a winner. Thanks so much zaf!

<?php
$i=0;
  while($i < $numberofrooms){ // 3 is the number of items in each array
 echo "<tr>";
  $j = 0;
  while($j < $numberofproducts){
   echo "<td>".$rows[$numberofrooms*$j+$i].'</td>';
   $j++;
  }
 $i++;
  }
?>
(I have no idea how to do the php code in comments, my apologies)

Comment: If you found this useful then you should be clicking the up arrow. Once will do ;)

Comment: Ahh I finally got it somehow! I gave it to you man. Preciate it.